Python DeepDiff Decimal comparison but with relative tolerence
I'm using DeepDiff module to compare JSON with a lot of data in it. I have two Json build similarly to that:
old = {
   "case_A":{
      "a":0.123456,
      "b":123456.7
   }
   "case_B":{
      ...
   }
   ...
}

new = {
   "case_A":{
      "a":0.13,
      "b":123456.8
   }
   "case_B":{
      ...
   }
   ...
}

Here, "a" values are low and "b" values are high. However, if I want to compare the values with a tolerance (using "math_epsilon" parameter), no tolerance values makes sense for every values.
If I set a tolerance of 0.01, "a" and "b" values will be considered different between old and new Json. But the difference for "b" is not significant and should not be detected. If I have a tolerance of 0.2, nor "a" or "b" values will be considered different, but the difference for "a" is significant.
What I would like to know is if there is any way to compare values relatively to the other (like a 0.1% tolerance) or if there is a way to change math_epsilon to change according to a name filter.
Or maybe there is a tool more adapted to what I want ?
The only solution I tried for now is kinda ugly. I run deepdiff with no tolerance and filter the results afterwards. Which works but is really time and space consuming for heavy files.

Take a look here: https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/current/numbers.html  I think it addresses your problem, by using scientific notation

In short, for OP, DeepDiff(old, new, number_format_notation="e", significant_digits=2) may be used. However, IMO this should be done with rel_tol, which they seemed to have intended to add, but then stopped.
